# Can I use a new version of a library that is loaded by the Mule system classloader?

Tags: mule

I have a dependency that requires a new version of com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.

Here is the maven config for that dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.5</version>
</dependency
```

Mule 3.7.0 uses version 2.4.3.

I've tried setting an override in the mule-deploy.properties file:

```
loader.override=com.fasterxml.jackson.databind
```

I've also tried using apache shade to re-locate/re-name the conflicting package with the following config:

```
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
 <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>2.3</version>
 <configuration>
   <artifactSet>
     <includes>
        <include>com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind</include>
     </includes>
   </artifactSet>
   <relocations>
     <relocation>
       <pattern>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</pattern>
       <shadedPattern>shaded.fasterxml.jackson.core.databind</shadedPattern>
     </relocation>
   </relocations>
  </configuration>
```

Is there something about either of the two above approaches that is wrong, or is there another way to include a conflicting version of a dependency in the pom that is also loaded in as a different version by the Mule System classloader?

Comment: did you ever work this out?